# How to start racoon VPN IKE negotiation automatically?

Tags: linux, vpn, ipsec

I have configured racoon at two ends (with pre-shared keys) and trying to establish tunnel. But I have to initiate traffic to start IKE negotiation.

Is there any alternative to establishing the tunnel automatically? If I don't send traffic to the remote end, the tunnel will not be established.

In StrongSwan there is `auto=[start|add]` option to disable/enable auto connect. But, I can't find any configuration in racoon.